# get specific datas from a array by a search

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array with many different data in there, I get the data from my server :

```
 $sp_bots = shell_exec("grep bot | awk '{print $12}' /var/www/laravel/logs/vhosts/website");
```

In this comment I get all data where the word 'bot' is there - and than I cut something out via `awk`

```
Mozilla/5.0 [82] => "Mozilla/5.0 [83] => "Googlebot-Image/1.0" [84] => "Googlebot-Image/1.0" [85]
```

is what I get now,

But I ONLY want the data where 'bot' is found! i just don't know how.. array_filter could make it but I don't know how and don't understand the syntax.

Comment: Do you get an array in response? The output response doesn't seem to be an array?

Comment: Array ( [0] => "Mozilla/5.0 [1] => "Mozilla/5.0 [2] => "Mozilla/5.0 [3]  and so on... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you get an array something like below then Try [PHP strpos function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$sp_bots= array( 82 => "Mozilla/5.0", 83 => "Googlebot-Image/1.0", 84 => "Googlebot-Image/1.0" );
foreach($sp_bots as $data) {
    if(strpos($data, 'bot' ) > -1 ) {
      // It does contain bot string
      echo $data .' contains bot string <br/>';//while it will print the other two indexes
    } else {
      // It does not contain bot value
      echo $data .' does not contains bot string <br/>'; //Mozilla/5.0 does not contain bot string
    }
}
```